# How to use a dynamic variable in query execution as a parameter in function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @value AS NVARCHAR(64) = 'value'

EXECUTE('SELECT w.id
         FROM myarray w
         WHERE LEN('+@value+') = 0')
```

I was wondering how I can use a declared value inside the `LEN` function in order to execute a query. Values `@expression` and `@value` change dynamically, therefore I want to use them inside this execution.

I am getting an error

> The len function requires 1 argument(s)

How is possible to  use a declared value as a parameter of a function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if `value` is only a string you need to wrap that variable with single quotes.

Comment: Like this: `...('''+@value+''')....`

Comment: Thank you @JorgeCampos it was helpful

Comment: Have a look at my answer, purely due to concerns of SQL Injection. For example. If you used `SET @Value = ''') = 0; CREATE TABLE dbo.Injection (ID int);--'` I'm pretty confident you'd have a new table [Injection] in your database.

Comment: @homeostasis did you have a look into the injection issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work. Try putting brackets around the column name in the dynamic sql:

```
execute('SELECT w.id
FROM myarray w
WHERE LEN(['+@value+']) = 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that @value has the name of a column, personally, I'd do it this way, using `sys.columns` and `sys.tables` to avoid SQL injection:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @Value nvarchar(64);
SET @Value = 'value';

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT w.IDENT_CURRENT
FROM myarray w
WHERE LEN(' + QUOTENAME([name]) + ') = 0;'
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.Columns c
WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id
  AND c.[name] = @Value;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Edit: If @Value is meant to be a persistant value, then do:

```
DECLARE @Value nvarchar(64) = 'value';

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT w.IDENT_CURRENT FROM myarray w WHERE LEN(@dValue) = 0;', N'@dValue nvarchar(64)', @dvalue = @Value;
```

Edit 2:

Further point, using the current answer from Jorge Campos. This is quite open to injection. For example, using the following create an extra table:

```
CREATE TABLE myarray2 (id int);

DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(64) = 'value'

SET @Value = ''') = 0; CREATE TABLE dbo.Injection (ID int);--'

EXECUTE('SELECT w.id
         FROM myarray2 w
         WHERE LEN('''+@value+''') = 0');

GO
SELECT *
FROM injection;

DROP TABLE injection;
DROP TABLE myarray2;
```

Please **always** considering SQL Injection when using Dynamic SQL. Jorge's answer comes with concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Hope this works for you (:

```
 DECLARE @value AS NVARCHAR(64) = 'value',
                       @String NVarchar(max)

          SET @String = 'SELECT w.id
                                     FROM myarray w
                                     WHERE 
          '+CONVERT(Varchar(20),LEN(@value))+'=0'

          EXECUTE (@String)
```